# How to make python loop remember each value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, lambda

Whenever I dynamically create buttons in tkinter through a loop, to call a function  with a value assigned to them through the loop, like so:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def add(text):
    print(text)
for i in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
    Button(root, text=i, command=lambda:add(i)).pack()
mainloop()
```

I always have the problem that the function is called with *the last value in the loop*, whatever button I press. In this case, it simply prints `c` whatever button I press. I do not know if this is a problem with `lambda` or `tkinter`, or simply my programming, but I would like to know how to fix it.

I have tried using `copy.copy`, `copy.deepcopy` (on the `lambda` function and the string), and `[:]` and `str` (on the string).

Comment: @Aran-Fey While the linked question's answer will provide me with a solution, it does not answer my question as it **defines functions**, and does not use `lambda`. When I try `lambda:add(text=i)`, I have the same problem.

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is. `lambda` is just a different way to define a function. (And if you read the answer(s) carefully, you'll find out that you need `lambda i=i:add(i)` instead of `lambda:add(text=i)`.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey `lambda i` takes `i` as a parameter, my function should not, it should just use `i` in the function.

Comment: If the optional parameter is really a problem, you can use the `make_f` solution proposed in the very same answer.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I have Realised what you meant earlier now. Thanks for patence and help. I don't know how to retract my reopen vote but I would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a common trick:

```
for i in ...:
    def command(i=i):
        add(i)
    Button(..., command=command)
```

It looks a little ugly, but it captures the current value of `i` in the default argument values. There are other ways to solve this problem but this solution is fairly succinct.

Comment: Just wondering, how did you answer a duplicate marked question? Is it a privelige?

Comment: I wonder if there was a race condition. I didn’t see the duplicate appear until I answered.

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if there were a short grace period.